# displaying multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

How do you display the output of a 2 dimensional arrays

Here's the code:

I know how to display both of them separately doing.

```
    foreach($Father as $value){
       echo $value[0] . " " . $value[1] . "<br />";
    }

  foreach($Son as $value){
       echo $value[0] . " " . $value[1] . "<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this  - it assumes that each father has exactly 1 son though

```
$i = 0;
foreach($Father as $value){
   echo $value[0] . " " . $value[1] . "<br />";
   echo "-" . $Son[$i][0] . " " . $Son[$i][1] . "<br />";
   $i += 1;

}
```

Comment: it still uses a foreach. `$i` is just an easy way to know what index you have so you can match father to son.